# how to make a show/hide toggle button with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, hide, show

Hi I have been trying to make a show/hide toggle button with jquery but I can only find buttons that show a div but none that hide it

below is one of the examples I found that shows a div but it doesn't let you hide it unless you click on another button. I would like to be able to use the same button to show and hide a div. I have multiple divs on my page and would like to be able to use jquery instead of javascript.

```
<html>
 <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var divname= this.value;
          $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
        });

      });
</script> 
     </head>
        <body>


 <div id="buttonsDiv"> 

  <input type="button" id="button1" class="buttons" value="div1"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button2" class="buttons" value="div2"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button3" class="buttons" value="div3"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button4" class="buttons" value="div4"></input>

  </div>

   <div>

     <div id="div1" style="display:none">
    Hello World
     </div>

     <div id="div2" style="display:none">
       Test
   </div>

        <div id="div3" style="display:none">
          Another Test
  </div>

     <div id="div4" style="display:none">
     Final Test
     </div>


         </div>


     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jQuery **IS** javascript!

Comment: I wrote tutorial on [How to create JQuery plugin to convert radio buttons into toggle buttons](http://sgeek.org/jquery-toggle-button-plugin-for-sliding-toggle-switches-sswitch/) and [Here you can see demo](http://www.demos.sgeek.org/sswitch-jquery-plugin-demo/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".buttons").click(function () {
  var divname= this.value;
  $("#"+divname).slideToggle().siblings().hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler use control's own toggle function.

```
$('.toggleButtons').click(function()
{
    $('control1, control2, ...').toggle();
});
```

Comment: would I have to have one toggle method for each button? since the div name would being controlled would be different

Comment: for each button yes I think so, but if you want multiple areas to be hidden/shown by a single button then separate then with comma, code updated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty simple script to make:

```
$('.buttons').click(function()
{
    var elementToShowOrHide = $('#' + $(this).val());

    if(elementToShowOrHide.is(':visible'))
       elementToShowOrHide.hide();
    else
       elementToShowOrHide.show();
});
```

Each click on the button would then toggle the visibility of the other element.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your script with this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".buttons").click(function () {
           $("#buttonsDiv div").hide()
          var divname= this.value;
          $("#"+divname).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The toggle() shouldn't be applied to the $(this) but to the div related to the clicked button.

Comment: What is `$("#buttonsDiv").child()` will give?

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tYKcw/1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
    var div= $("#"+this.value);
          div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
});
```

That should do it.

EDIT:

credit for toggle goes to @AtoMerZ. He had it first.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .toggle() method should help you:

```
$(".buttons").click(function () {
  var divname= this.value;
  $("#"+divname).toggle();
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toggle` method for showing and hiding an element. This will show/hide each div individually:

```
$(".buttons").click(function () {
  $("#" + this.value).toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want all the other `div`s to be hidden when the new one is shown:

```
$('.buttons').click(
    function() {
        $('div > div').hide();
        $('div > div').eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hG23V/).